# ¿Cómo trabajar con un ID que es tipo serial en la tabla?

Tags: php, html, postgresql

Hola compañeros tengo una pregunta fijense que tengo una tabla llamada clientes en mi BD (en postgresql) y un campo de la tabla se llama id_cliente que es tipo serial. Y tengo un formulario hecho en PHP y HTML.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer en mi formulario para que a la hora de enviar mis datos no me aparezca el siguiente error?

Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo integer: «oto» LINE 2: VALUES('oto','sdsdsdsdsdsd') ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\PruebaPostgres\conexion\guardar.php on line 13
Ocurrióo un error ! ERROR: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo integer: «oto» LINE 2: VALUES('oto','sdsdsdsdsdsd') ^

Supongo que este error es porque en la BD en la tabla tengo 3 campos pero a la hora de enviar los datos solo estoy enviando dos. Y el primero lo esta tomando como que si fuese el id_campo cuando realmente es el nombre del usuario.

Este es mi código de conexión a BD.

```
<?php

        //Conexión a la base de datos
        if($_REQUEST['nombre_usuario'] && $_REQUEST['apellido'])
        {
        pg_connect("dbname=postgres user=***** password=*******") or
        die("No se pudo realizar la conexi&oacute;n"); // Conexión a la base de datos

        //Envío de los datos 
        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO clientes
        VALUES('%s','%s')",$_REQUEST['nombre_usuario'],$_REQUEST['apellido']); /
        $query = pg_query($query);
        if($query){
        echo "El registro ha sido agregado";
        }else{
        echo "Ocurri&oacute;o un error ! ".pg_last_error();
        }
    }
```

?>

Comment: Especifica las columnas `INSERT INTO clientes (campo1, campo2) VALUES('%s','%s')` o envía los valores de todas las columnas `INSERT INTO clientes VALUES(null, '%s','%s')`, en este caso, valor nulo para la ID

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby, me funcionó bueno el valor null no me lo aceptó porque el campo es not null pero en vez de null puse default y me funcionó perfectamente. Mil gracias.